What stress function in terms of coordinate distances does classical MDS minimize?
In multidimensional scaling (MDS), the goal is to find a transformation of a set of data points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^p$ into the lower dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^k$ (e.g., for visualization purposes, $k=2$) such that the distances $d_{ij}^*$ in the mapped $k$-dimensional space are similar to the distances in the original space.
AFAIK, classical MDS assumes Euclidean distances and only considers linear transformations, i.e. $x_i^* = A x_i$ where $A$ has rank $k$. The result is equivalent to projecting on the eigen vectors corresponding to the $k$ largest eigen values of the covariance matrix of the points $x_i$, aka PCA.
Question: Which loss function in terms of the coordinate distances $d_{ij}$ and $d_{ij}^*$ does classical MDS minimize and where can I find a proof?
So far, I have found the following (contradictory) information:

Wikipedia gives two different loss functions, and the one in terms of distances is $\sum_{i,j} (d_{ij}-d_{ij}^*)^2$.
Mardia (1978) gives the loss function $\sum_{i,j} (d_{ij}^2 - (d_{ij}^*)^2)$, which is the same loss function mentioned in this answer on CV. This criterion is strange, because it goes to minus infinity when the distances in the transformed space are blown up. He cites Gower (1966) as a reference, but Gower only derived a spatial configuration for the $x_i$ from given Euclidean distances.
Udell et al. (2016) give on p. 10 a different loss function, for which I cannot see how it is related to distances in the original and transformed space, namely $\sum_{i,j}(( x_i)_j -\langle z_i, y_j\rangle)^2$ where $z_i$ are $n$ $k$-dimensional vectors and $y_i$ are $p$ $k$-dimensional vectors that are to be determined. Presumably (?), the $z_i$ are the transformed coordinates $x_i^*$.

References:

Mardia, Kanti V. "Some properties of clasical multi-dimesional scaling." Communications in Statistics-Theory and Methods 7.13 (1978): 1233-1241.
Gower, John C. "Some distance properties of latent root and vector methods used in multivariate analysis." Biometrika 53.3-4 (1966): 325-338.
Udell, Madeleine, et al. "Generalized low rank models." Foundations and Trends® in Machine Learning 9.1 (2016): 1-118.

